# Restarting a function in Python 3.4

Tags: python, function, return, python-3.4

I need help for my python assignment. We have to make a quiz program and I am having trouble with restarting a function.

I need something like continue, but instead runs the function again. Also, some tips on returning values from functions cant hurt! Thanks! ~Also, I just started using python 2 weeks ago, so this is pretty advanced to me. EDIT: Thanks to user: 2ps! :D

```
#Quiz YAY!
#
#Name Removed
#
#Version 1.0
#
score = 0;
modPassword = "200605015"
def modMode(score):
   print("Entering Overide Mode");
   print("Opening Overide Console")
   cmd = input("Enter Command call exit{} to exit:  ")
   if cmd == "corr":
      print("Adding one point")
      score=score+1
      return(score);
   elif cmd== "manScoreChng":
      score=int(input("What do want the score to be?"));
   elif cmd == 'stop{}':
      raise Exception('Quit by User')

score = modMode(score);
print(score);
```

Comment: Please indent property and use proper syntax. This code is currently invalid and would not run.

Comment: The indentation isn't valid. Please fix. Also -- semicolons are not statement terminators in Python. You need to learn the basics of the syntax.

Comment: `while True: modScore()` you also don't have to pass in score as it's already global.

Comment: @TylerSebastian As I said, I am very new to python and will need a bit more in depth explanation. Only if it wont bother you of course...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To capture the return of the `modMode` function, **just make sure you return something at the end**:

```
score = 0;
modPassword = "200605015"
def modMode(score):
   print("Entering Overide Mode")
   print("Opening Overide Console")
   cmd = input("Enter Command:  ")
   if cmd == "corr":
      print("Adding one point")
      score = score+1
   elif cmd == "manScoreChng":
      score = int(input("What do want the score to be?"))
   elif cmd == 'exit':
      raise Exception('Bye!')
   return int(score) # MAKE SURE YOU HAVE THIS LINE HERE
```

---

To call the `modScore` command over and over again, use a loop.

```
try:
  while True:
    score = modMode(score) # grab the returned value from modMode by using `=`
    print(score)
except Exception:
  pass
```

This will run until the user types in exit.

Comment: Ok, as I said I am new, and whatever you did worked! What is an exception? If you don't mind...

Comment: It’s used for a lot of things.  In this particular case, we’re just using it as a clever way for the function to let the caller know that the user has said that he or she doesn’t want to continue the loop anymore and immediately stops the loop.  The in-depth explanation is here (and exceptions are most commonly used for error handling):  https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

Comment: Entering Overide Mode
    Opening Overide Console
    Enter Command:  manScoreChng
    What do want the score to be?32
    0

Comment: I just copy & pasted my code and ran it and it doesn’t have the same output that you are getting.  Can you repost the entirety of your program?

Comment: Ok, I twiddled some things and got a None output and now understand execeptions

Comment: Btw, I am using python 3.4 IDK if you saw the tag

Comment: If what you have above is, indeed, the code that you are running, you didn’t follow the example carefully.  For the code to work as written by me, you have to have a return at the bottom of the function.  Take a close look, it will work in Python 3.4, 3.5, 3.5.2 and with minor adjustments, even python 2.7.